# Trying to set each piece of a list in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

```
   info = [[30.22,-81.88,VFR],[27.18,-80.22,VFR], [35.35,-89.87,MVFR]]
```

So here is a small portion of my list with lists inside. This is a short snippet of a longer list of 4700 lists inside my general list "info"

I need to basically take each of these values per list and put them into variables for example:
`info[1]` is `[30.22,-81.88,VFR]` and I need to set `lat[i] = 30.22, long[I] = -81.11, cat[I] = VFR`

then I will map these coordinates on OpenStreetMap and so on so forth.

So my question is how can I take each list and take out each value per each list?

my best guess is a for loop inside a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert each element into a tuple then split the tuple into variables or append each inner element to a list.

Split tuple:

```
info = [[30.22,-81.88,'VFR'],[27.18,-80.22,'VFR'], [35.35,-89.87,'MVFR']]

lat = [None] * len(info)
long = [None] * len(info)
cat = [None] * len(info)

for i,e in enumerate(info):
   lat[i], long[i], cat[i] = tuple(e)

print(lat)
print(long)
print(cat)
```

Append inner element:

```
info = [[30.22,-81.88,'VFR'],[27.18,-80.22,'VFR'], [35.35,-89.87,'MVFR']]

lat = []
long = []
cat = []

for e in info:
   lat.append(e[0])
   long.append(e[1])
   cat.append(e[2])
   
print(lat)
print(long)
print(cat)
```

List comprehension is also an option:

```
info = [[30.22,-81.88,'VFR'],[27.18,-80.22,'VFR'], [35.35,-89.87,'MVFR']]

lat =  [e[0] for e in info]
long = [e[1] for e in info]
cat =  [e[2] for e in info]
   
print(lat)
print(long)
print(cat)
```

All have the same result:

```
[30.22, 27.18, 35.35]
[-81.88, -80.22, -89.87]
['VFR', 'VFR', 'MVFR']
```